# Which jQuery url to use for production app and why?

Tags: jquery

I saw two url's for jquery today

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2

and

http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Which one should i use for my production app?

Which url is used by you in your production apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link is the jQuery served off Google's CDN... its what you need to use, and what gives you the biggest chance of the file already being present on the user's system. Its what everyone uses.

The second link is to download the file from the jQuery project repository. This file can (and will) be removed whenever the project owners release a new version. So you wouldn't want to use it on production :D

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/

Google recommends you use the google.load() function, but http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js also works.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct. It's the link that will get you a download from googles "as close as possible" content delivery network.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the second one is a download link ( which could still work ), I would use the first one because jQuery.com uses it :p

Comment: I must be blind. Can you point out where?
http://blog.jquery.com/2009/08/20/codejquerycom-redirected-to-google-ajax-apis/
In the `<head>` of jquery.com I still see the reference to google apis..

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). By using it, your application has high speed, globaly available access to the Javascript library. Although sometimes the library that is putted here is updated late. If that is not an issue for you I would recommend the first one.