# Does JavaScript disturb the loading of other content?

Tags: javascript, load

If I put JavaScript in the `head` tag as follows:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
// my jscript
  </script>

</head>
```

will it disturb the loading of other content such as pictures, text, etc.? I just argued with my friend; he said it will disturb the loading of the design of the website.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless you use `async` or `defer` then the javascript will load before the html content. You can move the script below all the images/text and put it before the end body tag.

Nowadays though, browsers are so fast that it's not that huge of an issue unless you have an overly complex site. Not to mention, jQuery gets faster and faster and more compact with each iteration.

One other aspect is that some modern browsers load multiple resources in parallel, so it's possible that it's not much of an issue in those browsers. I do not know the intricate details of this, maybe someone else will provide some insight...

Comment: A great! Thanks for a good reply. I do understand this a lot more now when u explained.

Comment: @Sinzo And if you're using jQuery (or another popular library) use a cache-friendly path on a CDN (content distribution network; moves data closer, makes it faster, in theory)! [Which jQuery url to use for production app and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535673/which-jquery-url-to-use-for-production-app-and-why) This takes advantage of that fact that the same library is used by many, many sites and can thus skip a new fetch entirely (if it's cached, but even if there is a query it will likely be faster on a CDN) -- the speed of light is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.

And this is why it is important to use a 'ready' callback (which is available within [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)). This is the proper way of ensuring that your code is executed only once the page has finished loading, which is what you want in most cases.

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          // my jscript
     }
  </script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will prevent page from the rendering until external script completes loading and finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with regards to the page loading faster:

Put CSS at the top, JavaScript at the bottom.  Steve Souders (High Performance Web Sites, O’Reilly)
found that moving stylesheets to the top in your head element makes pages load faster by allowing them to load
progressively.

With scripts, the opposite is true. If possible, move external JavaScript
files to the bottom of your pages, or delay or defer the loading of JavaScript files in
the head.

Progressive rendering is blocked for all content that is placed after scripts in
your HTML.